# Scale data range from [0,1] to [-1,1] in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with multiple float columns. I previously calculated the percentile ranks for each column using rank(pct=True) in pandas and stored them in another column, which I use for plotting an heatmap, therefore I don't have negative values in the rank columns. For visualization purposes, it would be better if I can transform the rank columns from [0,1] to [-1,1] range. I know it's not a common way to go, but would you have any suggestion for this? An example of the dataframe below

```
name r1    r2    r3
A    0.99  0.98  0.10 
B    1.00  0.50  0.00
C    0.99  0.15  0.90
```

expected output ( I don't know the intermediate values but the old 1.00 should still be 1.00, and the old 0.00 should be -1.00, and all other values scaled accordingly)

```
name r1    r2    r3
A    ...  ...  ... 
B    1.00 ...  -1.00
C    ...  ...  ...
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Please post your expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do some basic math operations to scale it:

```
(df-0.5)*2
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need the following simple function:

```
        (1-(-1))*(x-min)
f(x) =  ---------------- -1
            max - min
```

that is

```
2*(df-df.min())/(df.max()-df.min())-1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own function in pandas using `.max()` and `.abs()` or use the scikitlearn `MaxAbsScaler`, as detailed here: https://towardsdatascience.com/data-normalization-with-pandas-and-scikit-learn-7c1cc6ed6475